# Extract two lines of digits from a String

Tags: java, android, string

I have a gps module that sends strings of data to my Android app.

For example a string I get can look like this:

```
http:/maps.google.com/maps?q=59.0000000,16.0000000
```

How can i extract the numbers into two different strings.

Thanks on forehand

Comment: Well, how far have you got? Have you at least extracted the "59.0000000,16.0000000" part? If so, have you tried splitting on commas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Uri uri=Uri.parse(yourString);
String result=uri.getQueryParameter("q");
```

Then split your result with `,`,which gives you a `array` of strings (contains your numbers as strings).

Comment: Thanks, this was simple and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d+").matcher(str);
m.find();
String n1 = m.group();
m.find();
String n2 = m.group();
```

if the format is fixed then we can make it simpler

```
String[] str = "http:/maps.google.com/maps?q=59.0000000,16.0000000".replaceAll("\\D+(.+)", "$1").split(",");
String n1 = str[0];
String n2 = str[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

split() method of String class returns array of string so you can use following code:

String s = req.getParameter("q');
String[] arr = s.split(",");

String num1 = arr[0];
String num2 = arr[1];

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
String address = "http:/maps.google.com/maps?q=59.0000000,16.0000000";
String[] splited = address .split("=");
splited[0]; // this will contain "http:/maps.google.com/maps?q"
splited[1]; // this will contain "59.0000000,16.0000000"

String[] latlong = splited[1].split(",");

latlog[0]; // Should contain 59.0000000
latlog[1]; // Should contain 16.0000000
```

Cheers :-)